# Addition of vectors and matrix cells

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do modify my code to work with vectors and cant get around something that seems simple

I am getting the following error

```
"??? Error using ==> plus
Number of array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in ==> mesh_analysis at 57
 Y_mtx(1,1,1:N)=Y_mtx(1,1,1:N)+5./(R3*Zof_R1_C1_L1parrC2);"
```

now, `Zof_R1_C1_L1parrC2` is a vector of length N, and R3 is a scalar/number

how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems that the left-hand-side and right-hand-side of the `+` are not the same size.  You will need to fix that.

Comment: Everything is size 1XN, well the Y_mtx is a matrix of 3X3XN but i dont thing that this is the problem. its something with the division. but I dont know how to fix it. everything seems straightforward but doesnt work :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the size of `Y_mtx(1,1,1:N)` is `[1 1 N]` and therefore is is **different** than the size of `Zof_R1_C1_L1parrC2` which is `[1 N]` or `[N 1]`.

Note that despite the fact that the number of elements is the same, the size is **different**.

You may use `permute` to change the size of `Zof_...` to `[1 1 N]`.

Comment: In this case a reshape would be just fine. Permute in this particular case will give the same result, but isn't what you should be using to reshape the matrices.